# How to get a doc Id which is random or unknown in Flutter from firebasefirestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to count the unread chat to show the counts in notification and for this I need to know the doc ID which would be different each time and I am storing the chat like this:- [image]

```
collections('chats).doc(currentUser,otherUser).collection('messages').doc(autoGeneratedId)
```

Now, I don't know how to put a query to get these ID as it will be different each time with every other new User and further with new messages.Pls help.

I have tried these 2  ways of getting docID from the earlier answers but it shows errors:-

```
1:-

var docList = [];
messagesDoc.collection('collection')
           .get()
           .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
               snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => docList.add(doc)'));
           });


2:-


var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
var querySnapshots = await collection.get();
for (var snapshot in querySnapshots.docs) {
  var documentID = snapshot.id; 
}
```

Comment: You probably should think about saving the unread count as a field value on a document that refers to the chat thread. To reread the chats just to  determine if they have been read or not could end up costing you money.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, now pls help me further with this. How can I do that? In which way I should store the chat with the unread count field  as each chat will again have different id. And earlier I was thinking to check 'isRead' field whether its true or false.

Comment: I am guessing that the key of the chats document is the two user ids. I would keep the unread counts on that doc, probably one for each of the users. When a user writes a message you increment the relevant count, when a user reads the message you decrement the relevant count. Then you read only that doc to get the counts for that chat thread. Personally, I use realtime db for my chat facility so I haven't worked through it on Firestore.

Comment: ok i'll try that but how to get that doc id which is after chats, how can I get that? any idea and yes, chats document is two user ids. How can I get the value of  that id?

Comment: I'm on my phone so can't check anything. If you know the user's on the chat you already know the key. Or you can read it from the snapshot. Hopefully others can help you with this.

Comment: Hey there!, could you please tell me if you were able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference.id.toString()
```

after the update of null safety, you can get the document id by passing the index of the listview.