# How to copy one collection document id to another collection field in Cloud Firestore using Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to copy **Users** collection **documentid** to **Orders** collection **driverId**. Please Help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The function should be this.

```
void _setDriverId(){
    String userDocumentId = 'your_user_id';
    String orderDocumentId = 'your_target_order_id';
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Orders').doc(orderDocumentId)
       .update({'driverId': userDocumentId})
       .catchError((e) => print(e.toString()));
}
```

For more details related to real time changes to documents and collections you can refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying) and a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62968615/15774176) related to how to retrieve data from the collection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).