# How do I get and store document ID to Field in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get the document ID and store it in field, such as the document ID marked in red, and store in post_pid

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code you use to write the doc?

Comment: [Your query is entertained here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968486/how-do-i-get-documentid-of-a-firestore-document-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this while adding your data.

```
    const postDocRef=firebaseClient.firestore().collection('post_details').doc();
    await postDocRef.set({
      post_pid: postDocRef.id,
      // ....rest of your data
    });
```

We get a [document reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) first and then we get the `id` property.