# How to avoid creating multiple docs in firebase everytime user update his profile info in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So I just created a form for the user to key in his/her personal info in flutter.
This is the code as a begining:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class InsertProfInfoToDB {
  String? name;
  int? height;
  int? weight;
  String? gender;
  String? birthDateInString;
  InsertProfInfoToDB();

  Map <String, dynamic> toJson() => {'name': name, 'height': height,
    'weight' : weight, 'gender' : gender,
    'birthDateInString' : birthDateInString};

  InsertProfInfoToDB.fromSnapshot(snapshot)
      : name = snapshot.data()['name'],
        height = snapshot.data()['height'],
        weight = snapshot.data()['weight'],
        gender = snapshot.data()['gender'],
        birthDateInString = snapshot.data()['birthDateInString'];




}
```

```
 Future<void> submitForm () async {

 String userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

   int height =int.parse(heightController.text);
   int weight =int.parse(weightController.text);

   _insertProfInfoToDBToDB.name = nameController.text;
   _insertProfInfoToDBToDB.birthDateInString = birthDateInString;
   _insertProfInfoToDBToDB.height = height;
   _insertProfInfoToDBToDB.weight = weight;
   _insertProfInfoToDBToDB.gender = select;

   await FirebaseFirestore.instance
         .collection('users')
         .doc(userID)
         .collection('personalInfo')
         .add(_insertProfInfoToDBToDB.toJson());
 }
```

With this code, everytime I submit the form, a new doc will be created with the user info. How can I make it so that if the user info is exicted on the DB then update the new values to the same doc.

I tried to specify the name of the doc where the info is saved but I got an error saying

> The method 'add' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'.

Comment: hmmm i think is also need another docid in order to find the specific data if its update data dont use add use update()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use update method

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
         .collection('users')
         .doc(userID).update();
```

Comment: If I execute it this way, I will get an error saying "Some requested document was not found." because when it was first created inside the collection('personalInfo'), it was created under random  geberated doc ID

Comment: And if I want to specify the doc ID name when first creating the record, then I will get the error" The method 'add' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'."

Comment: I actually have solved it. I will post the code soon. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Since I had a collection that contains docs which contains collections, It was a bit tricky to get it done but here is how I did it.
First I created this function to get the doc ID and added it to initState with help from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67857128/18205996.

```
Future <void> getID () async {
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.
  collection('users').doc(userID).collection('personalInfo');
  var querySnapshots = await collection.get();
  for (var snapshot in querySnapshots.docs) {
    documentID = snapshot.id;
    print(documentID);
  }
}
```

Then the the Update function:

```
 Future<void> submitForm () async {
    int height =int.parse(heightController.text);
    int weight =int.parse(weightController.text);

    _insertProfInfoToDBToDB.name = nameController.text;
    _insertProfInfoToDBToDB.birthDateInString = birthDateInString;
    _insertProfInfoToDBToDB.height = height;
    _insertProfInfoToDBToDB.weight = weight;
    _insertProfInfoToDBToDB.gender = select;

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(userID).collection('personalInfo').doc(documentID)
        .update(_insertProfInfoToDBToDB.toJson());

  }
```