# convert 'Document' values' to a list in flutter (firedart)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, desktop-application

I am building a desktop application for Windows using Flutter. I am trying to retrieve all of the documents IDs from a collection in FireStore using the package [firedart](https://pub.dev/packages/firedart/example) (as the official FireStore package does not support Windows).

This is a simple code to get the documents from a collection:

```
FirebaseAuth.initialize(apiKey, VolatileStore());
Firestore.initialize(projectId);
CollectionReference stream = Firestore.instance.collection('users');
final data = await stream.get();
print(data);
```

The output of this print will be a list of arrays where each one has the path to the document and the values sorted inside the document.
for example:

[/users/1dfU7emalRX89z5zlfX0AQLqehq1 {url: '', name: '', height:'' , weight: '',}, /users/JF6PMb2q9Igsb56jgPRs1DGzJ0d2{url: '', name: '', height:'' , weight: '',}]

How can I print the Ids only to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get id from this collection by convert value to string and split this string to get it

'''[image]

'''

```
 /// to save return id only
List<String> ids = [];

/// first store return data in  List<dynamic>
List<dynamic> list = [
  "/users/1dfU7emalRX89z5zlfX0AQLqehq1 {'url': '', 'name': '', 'height':'' , 'weight': '',}",
  "/users/JF6PMb2q9Igsb56jgPRs1DGzJ0d2{url: '', 'name': '', 'height':'' , 'weight': '',}"
];

/// forEach element in list convert it to string
list.forEach((element) {
  /// it will return part of string as '/users/1dfU7emalRX89z5zlfX0AQLqehq1 '
  final String firstPartString = element.toString().split('{').first;

  /// split new string by / and it the last item (it is id)
  final String id = firstPartString.split('/').last;

  /// adding id to ids list (trim to remove any prefix of suffix space)
  ids.add(id.trim());
});

print(ids);
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

As I found from linked package's docs, API of the library you are using is similar to the official one.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62968615/10180836) might help - you can get document ID when you have a reference to the document